# Error: inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView in androidX

Tags: java, android, androidx, layout-inflater

My app working above API level 26 or higher but stoped working bellow API level 26. Please help me..

Why does XML returns error in inflating class, and stoped working in lower API level?

I tried these methods but it did not work:

Check your code for drawable and color resources used inside the com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView you've used, probably in activity_main.xml, if you're using the default Navigation Drawer template code from Android Studio.
Check that the drawable files are in res/drawable folder, not in res/drawable-v21.
Check if you've used android:backgroundTint() or android:src or similar inside your NavigationView. Since they don't work below android API Level 21, use app:backgroundTint or app:srcCompat instead.

...

```js
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bozorgan/com.example.bozorgan.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.bozorgan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main"/>
    

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:menu="@menu/menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Did you add the material dependency to your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the Drawerlayout library to the build.gradle(:app) file so you can use Drawerlayout.
If not, open the build.gradle(:app) file and add:
implementation "androidx.drawerlayout: drawerlayout: 1.1.1"

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidX NavigationView requires these dependencies and also check out Documentation for more Information [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies)

```
  // Java language implementation
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2"

  // Kotlin
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.2"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.2"
```